# How to combine multiple columns of an r data frame into a single column that is a list

Tags: r, list, dataframe, nested-lists

I would like to combine multiple columns that I have in a data frame into one column in that data frame that is a list. For example, I have the following data frame ingredients:

```
name1 name2 imgID attr1 attr2 attr3...
Item1 ItemID1 Img1 water chocolate soy...
Item2 ItemID2 Img2 cocoa spice milk...
```

I would like to combine the attr columns into one column that is a comma-separated list of those items and if possible have them appear in the following format:

```
name1 name2 imgID attrs
Item1 ItemID1 Img1 c("water", "chocolate", "soy", ...)
Item2 ItemID2 Img2 c("cocoa", "spice", "milk", ...)
```

Is there a succinct way to write the code using a paste or join that allows me to call the columns of the data frame as `ingredients[4:50]` rather than each one by name? Is there also a way to not include `NA` or `NULL` values in that list?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `tidyr::nest`, though you'll probably want to simplify the nested data frames to character vectors afterwards, e.g.

```r
library(tidyverse)

items <- tibble(name1 = c("Item1", "Item2"), 
                name2 = c("ItemID1", "ItemID2"), 
                imgID = c("Img1", "Img2"), 
                attr1 = c("water", "cocoa"), 
                attr2 = c("chocolate", "spice"), 
                attr3 = c("soy", "milk"))

items_nested <- items %>% 
    nest(contains('attr'), .key = 'attr') %>% 
    mutate(attr = map(attr, simplify))

items_nested
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#>   name1 name2   imgID attr     
#>   <chr> <chr>   <chr> <list>   
#> 1 Item1 ItemID1 Img1  <chr [3]>
#> 2 Item2 ItemID2 Img2  <chr [3]>
```

Other options include reshaping to long with `tidyr::gather`, grouping by all but the new columns, and aggregating the value column into a list in a more dplyr-focused style:

```r
items %>% 
    gather(attr_num, attr, contains('attr')) %>% 
    group_by_at(vars(-attr_num, -attr)) %>% 
    summarise(attr = list(attr)) %>% 
    ungroup()
```

or `unite`ing the `attr*` columns and then separating them within a list column with `strsplit` in a more string-focused style:

```r
items %>% 
    unite(attr, contains('attr')) %>% 
    mutate(attr = strsplit(attr, '_'))
```

or using `purrr::transpose` and tidyselect in a list-focused style:

```r
items %>% 
    mutate(attr = transpose(select(., contains('attr')))) %>% 
    select(-matches('attr.'))
```

All options return the same thing, at least on the sample data. Further cleanup, e.g. dropping `NA`s, can be done by iterating over the new column with `lapply`/`purrr::map`.

Comment: Does this work when you have some rows that are empty or they are not all filled with a value? For example, some of my items don't have the same number of attr. When I tried the first method I got the following messages: 'Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: argument is of length zero.
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(x, na.rm = na.rm) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf'

Comment: You can drop `NA`s with `mutate(attr = map(attr, na.omit))` or similar, but given the warning part, you're still going to have to account for the possibility that there's nothing left in the list element afterwards when summarizing it, e.g. by using control flow in `map`, e.g. `map(attr, ~if(length(.x) == 0 NA else ...)`