# Nesting and combining data columns while changing type of nested objects

Tags: r, tidyr, nested-lists, purrr, tibble

I'm given a "reference" data frame that summarizes which variables in my main data (not shown here) should be filtered and by what values. Two such variables, for example, are `age` and `color`:

- `age` should be filtered according to a range of values
- `color` should be filtered according to specific values.

**Here's an example for such "*filtering reference table*" I'm given for `age` and `color`:**

```r
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)

my_filter_ref_df <-
  structure(
    list(
      var_name = c("age", "colors"),
      min = c(18L, NA),
      max = c(60L, NA),
      values = list(NULL, c("blue", "orange",
                            "yellow", "purple")),
      filtering_type = c("range", "specific")
    ),
    row.names = c(NA,-2L),
    class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
  )

##   var_name   min   max values    filtering_type
##   <chr>    <int> <int> <list>    <chr>         
## 1 age         18    60 <NULL>    range         
## 2 colors      NA    NA <chr [4]> specific 


## and just to get a sense of the nested data:
my_filter_ref_df %>% unnest_wider(values)

##   var_name   min   max ...1  ...2   ...3   ...4   filtering_type
##   <chr>    <int> <int> <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>         
## 1 age         18    60 NA    NA     NA     NA     range         
## 2 colors      NA    NA blue  orange yellow purple specific
```

#### Desired Output

The current format of `my_filter_ref_df` is inconvenient. I want to have just the  filtering values in one column, as each row pertains to a different variable in the main data. This way, when I'll need to quickly reference to this table, I could always do it using the same code, regardless of the variable being queried.

So I need to (1) combine `min` and `max` values to one object, and (2) nest that object in `values` column (in `my_filter_ref_df` we already have a `values` column). So I'm aiming for an output that looks like the following `nested_df`.

```r
library(purrr)

nested_df <-
  structure(
  list(
    var_name = c("age", "colors"),
    values = list(c(min = 18L, max = 60L),
                  c("blue", "orange", "yellow", "purple")),
    filtering_type = c("range",
                       "specific")
  ),
  row.names = c(NA,-2L),
  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
)

## # A tibble: 2 x 3
##   var_name values    filtering_type
##   <chr>    <list>    <chr>         
## 1 age      <int [2]> range         
## 2 colors   <chr [4]> specific

> nested_df %>% purrr::chuck("values")
## [[1]]
## min max 
##  18  60 

## [[2]]
## [1] "blue"   "orange" "yellow" "purple"
```

### My attempt

I've seen a similar solved problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48837175/6105259). So I've tried this:

```r
library(dplyr)

my_filter_ref_df %>%
  nest(values_2 = c(min, max)) %>% 
  mutate(values_2 = map(values_2, simplify))

##             __________________________
##            |                                      |
##   var_name |values    filtering_type values_2     
##   <chr>    ↓<list>    <chr>          <list>       |
              ********                               
## 1 age      *<NULL>*    range          <int [2]> --|
              ********
## 2 colors   <chr [4]>   specific       <int [2]>
```

Using this unicode art I'm trying to demonstrate that the vector in `values_2` (for `age`) should actually be in `values` column instead of the current `NULL`, and `values_2` column shouldn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is treat separately by filtering_type:

```
# filtering_type == "range"
a <- my_filter_ref_df %>%
  filter(filtering_type == "range") %>% 
  nest(values2 = c(min, max)) %>% 
  mutate(values = map(values2, simplify)) %>% 
  select(-values2)

# filtering_type == "specific"
b <- my_filter_ref_df %>%
  filter(filtering_type == "specific") %>% 
  select(-min, -max)

# rbind 
nested_df <- rbind(a, b)
```

Comment: Thanks! This indeed is a working solution. However, I'm hoping to come up with code that does the wrangling without assigning different data objects and binding later.